# Selenium tests, Continuous Integration. The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cruisecontrol.net

I am running selenium tests using a cruisecontrol and lot of tests have failed with the same error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:7055/hub/session/18ebd740-f48e-4be2-bd84-a24f645cad2a/element/%7Bf6d3eb90-dadb-46f1-83e9-d022ccfc81fb%7D/click timed out after 60 seconds. 
    ----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out 
    TearDown : System.ArgumentException : Illegal characters in path. 
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request) 
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute) 
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute) 
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) 
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Click() 
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects.WebElementProxy.Click() 
    .....
```

This error occurs when using build server. The same tests work fine if running from VS and NUnit runner.

Comment: Try to clean up your post a little. It is very hard to read what is happening. From what I can see there is some problem with the web service you query. Is this service present on the build server?

Comment: which service? @Nitram

Comment: Your test is accessing `http://localhost:7055/hub/session/`... is this accessable at your test environment?

Comment: localhost:7075 is the port of the web driver - that is driving Firefox in your case - not the address you are telling it to navigate to.

Comment: You appear to have the driver setup to capture screenshots. It is failing here with an invalid path exception, are you able to see if it fails with this feature turned off?